# How to close a div at every 10?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need the following X3

```
<div class="row>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my take

```
$rows = 0;
$numPost = 0;
while($rows < 2 ) {
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col"><div class="carousel">';
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ) );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    ?>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            //content....
        </div>
    <?php
        $numPost++;  
        if($numPost % 10 == 0) {
            $numPost = 0;
            echo '</div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col"><div class="carousel">';
        }  
    }
    echo '</div></div></div>';
    $rows++; 
    if($rows = 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

But at the end of the three it gives me an empty row as per the following:

```
<div class="row>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="carousel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting results; enable error reporting. This by also changing the assignment operator to a comparison. I just can't use `get_posts()` so I had to remove it. This is a WordPress function so I added that tag.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yea forgot the wp tag thanks

Comment: Welcome. I got this back from HTML source: `<div class="row"><div class="col"><div class="carousel">        <div class="carousel-cell">
            //content....
        </div>
            <div class="carousel-cell">
            //content....
        </div>
    </div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col"><div class="carousel">        <div class="carousel-cell">
            //content....
        </div>
            <div class="carousel-cell">
            //content....
        </div>
    </div></div></div>`. So I think it's the `get_posts()` that might be failing here also.

Comment: Don't re-open your divs when you close it in your `$numpost` check. Instead, do not reset `$numpost`, and do the same sort of check at the beginning of the loop and echo the opening divs. Or create a flag for `$closed_div` and reset it when you close the divs, so you can re-open it at the top of the loop. You'll need to do the same sort of check after your loop so you don't close the divs twice.

Comment: @aynber a code example would of much help also for future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to not repeating rows is to not re-open the tags when you close them. You'll want to have the same check at the beginning of the loop to open the tags as you do later to close them. You'll need to double-check after the loop so that you do not close the divs twice.

```
$rows = 0;
$numPost = 0;
while($rows < 2 ) {

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ) );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        if($numPost % 10 == 0) {
            echo '<div class="row"><div class="col"><div class="carousel">';
        }
        ?>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            //content....
        </div>
        <?php
        $numPost++;
        if($numPost % 10 == 0) {
            $numPost = 0;
            echo '</div></div></div>';
        }
    }
    if($numPost %10 != 0) {
        echo '</div></div></div>';
    }

    $rows++;
    if($rows = 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The other way to do it would to be have a `$closed_div` variable that you can use as a flag. Have `$closed_div` set to true at the beginning, and then reset it when you open and close your divs.

```
    $closed_div = true;
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        if($closed_div) {
            echo '<div class="row"><div class="col"><div class="carousel">';
            $closed_div = false;
        }
        ?>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            //content....
        </div>
        <?php
        $numPost++;
        if($numPost % 10 == 0) {
            $numPost = 0;
            echo '</div></div></div>';
            $closed_div = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$closed_div) { // Div has not been closed
        echo '</div></div></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! used the first bit of code and makes sense. Thank you

Comment: any idea why we need to do `if($rows = 3) {` even tho we are doing `while($rows < 2 ) {` and also why we need `= 3` and not `== 3` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need it at all, especially since you're incrementing $rows. At the moment, what it's doing is stopping after the first iteration because you reassign $rows to 3. From what it looks like, at the moment you'd be reiterating through get_posts 3 times, so you probably don't need the row check at all.

Comment: tried to remove it but i gets all repeated and it doesn't break, anyway, it works so..

Answer (score 1):

First check your last if statement, it would be:

```
    if($rows == 3) {
    break;
}
```

Instead of:

```
    if($rows = 3) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: i tried it, but if I give that, then it doesn't break

Answer (score 0):

The whole break statement is redundant seeing as the loop only runs while `$rows < 2` so as soon as `$rows` reaches 3 the while loop condition is broken and the loop is stopped. There doesn't seem to be a reason for the loop not working.

I tested the code but replaced the while conditiion with `while($rows < 3)` to satisfy your three times condition. I removed

```
if($rows = 3) {
   break;
}
```

for it is not necessary.

Comment: well if I remove the break, it keeps going and it doesn't stop at 3. And keeping the break, it places an empty row as per the quetsion

Comment: this is a comment btw not an answer

Comment: keeps repeating the rows

Comment: I cannot comment on a post that isn't my own (my reputation being too low) so that's why I could not do anyting else but post it as an answer. I edited the answer after running it trhough an interpreter and it just runs three times.